# ASP.NET Url Rewriting With Response.RedirectToRoute()

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I Have a Global.asax file in that i written

routeCollection.MapPageRoute("GotoPage", "Default.aspx/{*Id}", "~/Default.aspx");

From aspx Page i called like

Response.RedirectToRoute("GotoPage", new { Id = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString() });

It Redirects to http://mysite.com/GotoPage/2.

Now The Problem Is. With that URL aspx page unable to load JQuery, CSS, Javascript Files. It says that invalid file path ( at runtime )

can help would be appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

In your masterPage, make sure that the paths to your files look like this

```
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl ("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link id="stMain" href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: If It Works with Localhost Then it's not working with IIS. if it works with IIS it's not working with localhost.